# How to modify osx homebrew formula to run on wider variety of systems?

Tags: macos, openssl, homebrew, autotools

I am installing the `openssl` package via osx homebrew. I however need to tweak the compilation process, but i cannot even find where/how homebrew is compiling my packages. I specficially would like to see what CFLAGS and **most importantly** the value of the `-march=` flag.

I looked in the logs `~/Library/Logs/Homebrew` and also in the homebrew 'formula' for openssl.

Basically i would like to modify this formula so it builds a very general `openssl` that i can distribute and bundle with my application, that works on a wide variety of systems.

Currently when i distribute the `libssl` and `libcrypto` versions built by `homebrew`, i get `illegal instruction` errors when i try to run them on some olders systems... but i would like to tweak the build flags so they can run on a wide variety.

Comment: I don't know about the Homebrew part of the problem... But usually you use [`-force_cpusubtype_ALL`](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Darwin-Options.html) to reach the widest variety of CPUs for an architecture. There may be a Framework part of the problem, but I have never built a framework of OS X.